# Опредение языка введенного в текстовое поле

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Как при помощи регулярных выражений сделать проверку кириллицы/латиницы. К примеру, если мы ввели в поле слова на английском, то выполнить такой-то метод, и соответственно для русского языка.

Comment: Проверку языка - никак. Если же нужно проверять только кириллицу/латиницу -  в гугл.

Comment: Вы представляете, сколько всего есть языков? Забудьте об определении языка, максимум что можно — это сопоставить наборы символов. Отделить английский от, скажем, французского невозможно.

Comment: Вы не поняли, я имел ввиду определить если мы ввели кириллицу, то вызвать один метод, если же с латиницей, то другой.

Comment: VladD, но в большинстве случаев с этой задачей научились неплохо справляться. Даже есть сервисы, которые предоставляют API ( http://detectlanguage.com/ например ).

Comment: @dzhioev:

1. Возьмём слово "cousin". Оно имеет смысл и на английском, и на французском, следовательно, если ввод содержит только это слово, мы в тупике. Ещё меньше различий между, скажем, немецким и швейцарским вариантами немецкого.

2. Язык можно угадать с определённой достоверностью, исходя из большой базы данных слов, а лучше — текстов. Причём [нестандартные тексты](http://www.stihi-rus.ru/1/Hlebnikov/3.htm) скорее всего распознаны не будут.

3. Построить базу данных слов всех возможных языков — довольно трудоёмкая, хоть и выполнимая задача, вы не находите?

Answer (score 5):

Регекспами это не делается (точнее, делается, но очень хрупко и очень неточно). Лучше всего делать частотный анализ символов, для латиницы вы должны получить... Да фиг знает, вот прошёлся по первому попавшемуся файлу на английском (около 330 Kb):

```
32  => 29.40% (96622)
!   => 0.04% (121)
"   => 1.45% (4762)
#   => 0.13% (412)
$   => 0.46% (1524)
%   => 0.07% (229)
&   => 0.02% (72)
'   => 0.28% (926)
(   => 0.46% (1526)
)   => 0.46% (1526)
*   => 0.10% (325)
+   => 0.02% (74)
,   => 1.09% (3598)
-   => 0.26% (860)
.   => 0.76% (2482)
/   => 0.12% (382)
0   => 1.42% (4654)
1   => 0.24% (801)
2   => 0.16% (539)
3   => 0.08% (255)
4   => 0.10% (322)
5   => 0.06% (204)
6   => 0.08% (266)
7   => 0.05% (154)
8   => 0.08% (272)
9   => 0.03% (99)
:   => 0.23% (756)
;   => 0.27% (882)
<   => 0.07% (228)
=   => 0.25% (815)
>   => 0.10% (321)
?   => 0.01% (41)
@   => 0.09% (304)
A   => 0.27% (895)
B   => 0.08% (272)
C   => 0.18% (585)
D   => 0.14% (450)
E   => 0.37% (1210)
F   => 0.16% (540)
G   => 0.06% (195)
H   => 0.10% (337)
I   => 0.40% (1329)
J   => 0.01% (24)
K   => 0.04% (131)
L   => 0.23% (747)
M   => 0.08% (269)
N   => 0.21% (696)
O   => 0.20% (663)
P   => 0.23% (753)
Q   => 0.01% (19)
R   => 0.26% (853)
S   => 0.34% (1129)
T   => 0.37% (1215)
U   => 0.08% (277)
V   => 0.06% (186)
W   => 0.05% (148)
X   => 0.09% (305)
Y   => 0.06% (185)
Z   => 0.01% (39)
[   => 0.03% (98)
\   => 0.08% (249)
]   => 0.03% (97)
^   => 0.02% (54)
_   => 0.20% (646)
`   => 0.01% (19)
a   => 4.15% (13651)
b   => 0.84% (2761)
c   => 1.90% (6239)
d   => 1.93% (6328)
e   => 7.55% (24821)
f   => 1.61% (5290)
g   => 0.98% (3211)
h   => 2.22% (7281)
i   => 4.03% (13233)
j   => 0.04% (121)
k   => 0.37% (1232)
l   => 2.63% (8643)
m   => 1.45% (4753)
n   => 4.01% (13195)
o   => 3.95% (12988)
p   => 1.45% (4780)
q   => 0.08% (266)
r   => 3.75% (12320)
s   => 4.09% (13445)
t   => 5.40% (17759)
u   => 1.90% (6257)
v   => 0.55% (1802)
w   => 0.64% (2089)
x   => 0.34% (1125)
y   => 0.98% (3235)
z   => 0.05% (164)
{   => 0.09% (303)
|   => 0.03% (95)
}   => 0.09% (299)
~   => 0.01% (23)

total: 328678 (100.00%)
```

Очевидно, если текст будет на кириллице, распределение будет совершенно другим. Хотя в области знаков (НЕ a-zA-Z) может оказаться и таким же.

Да, конечно же тут идёт речь об анализе алфавита, но ни в коем случае НЕ ЯЗЫКА.

Comment: В принципе, можно составить подобную табличку для пар (или троек) букв и посчитать к примеру для английского и немецкого - распределение явно будет разным, по крайней мере для каких-то характерных сочетаний. Тогда можно будет говорить об определении языка. Кстати, интересная тема для исследования

Comment: Определение по парам тоже используется, и оно достаточно надёжно. Например, для восстановления текста из "ломаных" перекодировок а-ля win/koi/iso/utf, etc.

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется, что ТС спрашивает о куда более простой вещи — просто узнать, вводит ли юзер русские символы или английские (типа, чтоб возле поля ввода пароля отобразить RU или EN).

Если так, то лучше использовать API оси для получения активной раскладки. Если же нужно определить, символы какого языка преобладают в тексте, то можно поступить как-то так:

    if (str.replace(/[a-z]/i, '').length < str.replace(/[а-я]/i, '').length)
        language = EN;
    else
        language = RU;

Извиняюсь за не C#, думаю, суть понятна

Comment: @Bars, спасибо, КО!

Задача, интересующая ТС решается тривиально, и потому не интересна. Задача определения языка по предложению/слову записанному латиницей более интересна, хотя конечно же не имеет 100% правильного решения.

Answer (score 1):

Для определения языка будет достаточно следующего простого кода:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string enWord = "Test";
        const string ruWord = "Тест";

        if (enWord.Any(wordByte => wordByte > 127))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Russian Language Detected in enWord");
        }

        if (ruWord.Any(wordByte => wordByte > 127))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Russian Language Detected on ruWord");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: He wrote "сам такой", that it means?

Какой язык определится?

Comment: `wordByte > 127`, сильно. А как вы китайский отличать собрались от французского?

Comment: Вопрос читали?Необходимо определение "кириллицы/латиницы", т.е. о смешанных предложениях "кириллица и латиница" никто не говорил.

To VladD: О китайском и французском вы где в вопросе прочитали?

Comment: @MxMaxxtor, а вот ни Вы, ни остальные авторы, отвечавшие ранее, совершенно не обратили внимание, что есть много кодировок кириллицы (в т.ч. utf-8) и это сильно (на практике) усложняет задачу, по сути делая неработоспособными предложенные подходы (без соответствующей их модификации).

Comment: @avp, здесь упоминались частоты пар, а не отдельных букв. Принцип-то тот же.

Comment: А вообще, если это не расшифровщик, то мы вполне можем полагаться на чарсет из HTTP-заголовков.

Comment: @avp .NET Framework хранит строки в Unicode. Коды в стандарте Юникод разделены на несколько областей. Область с кодами от U+0000 до U+007F содержит символы набора ASCII с соответствующими кодами.
Таблица ASCII до 127 СОДЕРЖИТ АНГЛИЙСКИЙ АЛФАВИТ, знаки пунктуации, цифры и непечатаемые знаки (которые нам в данном случае не важны). Для определения языка символов из двух вариантов (кириллицы/латиницы) этого более чем достаточно!

Comment: @klopp, а при чем здесь частоты пар?  

Вы подразумеваете более успешное распознавание кодировки статистическими методами на меньшей выборке?

В любом случае (что с парами-тройками, что без них) на сотнях символов статистика языка успешно сработает.

Смотрите, все разговоры в этой теме это либо выбор одного из нескольких языков по тексту в одном алфавите (англ., нем., фр. и т.п.) или определение одного из двух алфавитов (для выделения русского).

Я же, по сути, говорю об определении используемого алфавита, а не языка.

Согласитесь, на статистике Киргизского (тоже кириллица)  ... (места мало).

Comment: @MxMaxxtor, тогда уж сразу говорите, что речь о юникоде 

(кстати, какое его представление (utf-8, utf-16, ucs2be, ucs4le ..., с BOM или без) Вы имеели в виду при написании своего кода?),

это принципиально меняет задачу (лишает ее смысла).

--

И еще, а разве ТС говорил об юникоде?

Comment: @avp, я говорю о чём-то вроде [этого](http://popoff.donetsk.ua/file/text/libs/a.charset.php). Думаю, для других алфавитов подход тоже сгодится.

Comment: @klopp, зачем Вы подсовываете мне какую-то загрузку? Словами нельзя?

--

Я примерно представляю тему (писал распознаватели). Просто решил обратить внимение обсуждающих на обилие кодировок русского и связанное с этим усложнение решений.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить необычный способ:

1. берем произвольных 2-4 слов из текста
2. отправляем в API Google переводчика
3. если смогли перевести с английского - значит текст английский, если не смогли, то проверяем можно ли его перевести с русского.
   :)

В общем, решение зависит от постановки задачи и ее контекста.

Comment: 1) Как был получен диапазон 2-4?
3) Почему вы считаете, что если гугл-переводчик перевел с английского, то исходный текст был английским?

Comment: 1) я лишь предположил. автору (Если выберет предложенный мной вариант) нужно будет подобрать свое число слов.
2) если гугл перевел большую часть слов, то можно с определенной вероятностью утверждать, что язык найден.
еще раз повторю зависит от контекста. если программа автора подразумевает использование только русского и английского (что немаловероятно), то мой метод вполне подходит. и язык будет определяться однозначно.

Answer (score 0):

Если предполагается, что запрос с кириллицой можно считать русским, а запрос её не содержащий - английским:

Способ 1 - используем `Regex.IsMatch`

```
static bool IsRussian(string text)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(text, "[а-яА-ЯеЁ]");
}
```

Способ 2 - с использованием строковой константы

```
static bool IsRussian(string text)
{
    const string russianLetters = 
        "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    return text.Any(letter => russianLetters.Contains(letter));
}
```

Способ 3 - выдираем с помощью кодов Юникода все русские символы в отдельное множество/список

```
static bool IsRussian(string text)
{
    var russianLetters = new HashSet<char>();
    for (int i = 1040; i < 1072; i++)
    {
        russianLetters.Add((char)i); // верхний регистр
        russianLetters.Add((char)(i + 32)); // нижний регистр
    }
    russianLetters.Add((char)1025); // Ё
    russianLetters.Add((char)1105); // ё

    var isRussian = text.Any(x => russianLetters.Contains(x));

    return isRussian;
}
```

Подробнее про последний способ можно почитать тут: http://csharpprogramming.ru/uroki-po-c/kak-mozhno-bystro-poluchit-vse-bukvy-russkogo-ili-anglijskogo-alfavita